# What are the differences between VirtualBox and VMware Workstation?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I am planning to download a virtual machine and I'm confused which to download. If any one know more about virtual machines please give me a quick solution. If there is other virtual machines better then these, please tell me.

Comment: Suplementary question How do they differ in ability to share files between host and guest (and between guests)

Comment: It should be noted that this question and its answers are subject to change without notice. The page that Mehper linked to was for older versions of both program from several years ago and newer versions will pretty much certainly be different and could even counter the previous results.

Answer (score 6):

See the following blog entries for a pretty good comparison together with pros and cons of VMware vs. VirtualBox:

- [VMware vs. VirtualBox](http://marsbox.com/blog/reviews/vmware-vs-virtualbox/)
- [VMware vs. VirtualBox Part 2](http://marsbox.com/blog/reviews/vmware-vs-virtualbox-part-2/)

Comment: I would say the last pages is the best http://marsbox.com/blog/reviews/vmware-vs-virtualbox/6/

Answer (score 0):

May be below will help :

- Virtual Box is free while for VMWare you have to pay
- But as far as ease of access is concerned I would vote VMWare
- From stability point of view also , VMWare is better but being in IT I do not think that it does matter a lot as you can quickly fix issues of VirtualBox too.

(Usually I have issues when my AutoUpdate on Fedora is "ON" and kernel is updated but then VirtualBox remains old and it takes some time to get the updated package)

I fixed it by stopping auto-update and then installing packages I want.